# How can i make dynamic 2 column list

Tags: html, css, flexbox, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui framework. I add or remove from this list with jquery.
how can i make it with 2 columns.
first Column=1 2 3 4 5
Second Column= 6 7 8 9
or
first Column=1 2
Second Column= 3

can i do it with html css?
do i have to do it with jquery? I don't want to do it with jquery
he code is as follows.

```html
<div id="popup-custom" style="display:none;">
  <div class="ui two grid">
    <div class="column" style="flex: 1;">
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checked disabled checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" disabled="" name="List" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked=""><label>List</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="CreateFolder" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2"><label>@lang.CreateFolder</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="CreateFile" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4"><label>@lang.CreateFile</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Delete" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8"><label>@lang.Delete</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Download" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16"><label>@lang.Download</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Upload" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32"><label>@lang.Upload</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Share" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="64"><label>@lang.Share</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Link" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="128"><label>@lang.Link</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Rename" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="256"><label>@lang.Rename</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="View" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="512"><label>@lang.View</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Move" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="1024"><label>Move</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Copy" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2048"><label>@lang.Copy</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Edit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4096"><label>@lang.Edit</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="DocumentEdit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8192"><label>@lang.DocumentEdit</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="OpenWithDesktop" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16384"><label>@lang.OpenWithDesktop</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="ArchiveOperation" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32768"><label>@lang.ArchiveOperation</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Note" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="65536"><label>@lang.Note</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="UserLabel" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="131072"><label>@lang.UserLabel</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Favorite" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="262144"><label>@lang.Favorite</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Version" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="262144"><label>@lang.Version</label></div>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Lock" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="524288"><label>@lang.Lock</label></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help/advice would help. Thank you.

Comment: semantic-ui seems to be missing the column CSS rules , that you could easily use for such a list layout. basicly, you need to drop the flexbox class and use a class (or id) of your own with the rule : `column-count:2;` It will dispatch your items into 2 columns filling  one after the other.that it is 3 or 9 or 20  elements. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns -/- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: ... try `<div class="column"  style="column-count:2">` instead of  `<div class="column" style="flex: 1;">` if that's easier for you ...

Comment: thank u my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS flex, a flex parent make every child be in column (like you want)

```css
#popup-custom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup-custom">

    <!-- first column -->
    <div>
      <!--  -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checked disabled checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" disabled="" name="List" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked=""><label>List</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 2 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="CreateFolder" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2"><label>@lang.CreateFolder</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 3 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="CreateFile" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4"><label>@lang.CreateFile</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 4 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Delete" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8"><label>@lang.Delete</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 5 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Download" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16"><label>@lang.Download</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 6 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Upload" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32"><label>@lang.Upload</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 7 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Share" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="64"><label>@lang.Share</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 8 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Link" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="128"><label>@lang.Link</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 9 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Rename" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="256"><label>@lang.Rename</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 10 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="View" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="512"><label>@lang.View</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second column -->
    <div>
      <!-- 1 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input class="popup-specific" name="Move" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="1024"><label>Move</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 2 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Copy" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2048"><label>@lang.Copy</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 3 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Edit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4096"><label>@lang.Edit</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 4 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="DocumentEdit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8192"><label>@lang.DocumentEdit</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 5 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="OpenWithDesktop" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16384"><label>@lang.OpenWithDesktop</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 6 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="ArchiveOperation" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32768"><label>@lang.ArchiveOperation</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 7 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Note" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="65536"><label>@lang.Note</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 8 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="UserLabel" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="131072"><label>@lang.UserLabel</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 9 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Favorite" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="262144"><label>@lang.Favorite</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 10 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Version" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="262144"><label>@lang.Version</label></div>
      </div>
      <!-- 11 -->
      <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="popup-specific" name="Lock" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="524288"><label>@lang.Lock</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```